# What is the best way to test a custom assertion using google test in C++?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am getting started with c++ unit testing. I have been verifying an assert macro using the google test framework. I am using `LOG_FATAL` to print the `ASSERT(...)` error message. I am also aborting the process by `std::abort()` if the log type is `FATAL`.

my unit test:

```
TEST(Logger_DeathTest, assertionTest) {
    int test_val = 5;
    EXPECT_DEATH(SN_ASSERT(test_val < 0, "Value should not be less than zero"), "*");
    exit(0);
}
```

Failed test output:

```
Logger_DeathTest.assertionTest
   Source: logger_test.cpp line 112
   Duration: < 1 ms

  Message: 
    
    !! This test has probably CRASHED !!
    Test output:
    
    C:\dev\robo-galaxy\supernova\third_party\googletest\googletest\src/gtest-port.cc(869): error: Failed
    Syntax error at index 0 in simple regular expression "*": '*' can only follow a repeatable token.
    Running main() from ../../../third_party/googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
    ../../../tests/logging/logger_test.cpp(116): error: Death test: { if (!(test_val < 0)) { SN::Log::LogMessageShink_C(SN::Log::LogSeverityLevel_C::LOG_FATAL, "../../../tests/logging/logger_test.cpp",  __FSTREXP __FUNCTION__   , 116) .GetStream() << "Assertion Failed: " << "test_val < 0" << " :: " << "Value should not be less than zero"; __debugbreak(); } }
        Result: died but not with expected error.
      Expected: contains regular expression "*"
    Actual msg:
    [  DEATH   ] [Sat Jun 26 19:47:54 2021] [../../../tests/logging/logger_test.cpp:116 Log_Test::Logger_DeathTest_assertionTest_Test::TestBody] [FATAL] :: Assertion Failed: test_val < 0 :: Value should not be less than zero
    [  DEATH   ] [ERROR] : A fatal log has been encountered.
    [  DEATH   ]
```

Could someone please help to pass my unit test successfully?

Thank you!

Comment: I found one thing in their documentation, GTEST_SKIP() << "Skipping single test"; could be one option.

Comment: The second argument to `EXPECT_DEATH` is a regular expression. It is used to match the error message written to `stderr`. Use `".*"` (notice the `.` before the `*`) to match any message.